# Why does ServerSocketChannel#bind require API level 24?

Tags: java, android, nio

I'm trying to open a NIO server socket channel as follows on Android (min API 21).

```
ServerSocketChannel.open().also {
    it.bind(InetSocketAddress(0))
}
```

But the above code gives me an error saying that - **Call requires API level 24**. In theory, I can use the `ServerSocket` and call it a day, but my client code is using `SocketChannel`, `ByteBuffer` etc. and mixing the two feels like a bad design!

Another thing that confuses me is that I can `open()` it at min API level 21 but can't `bind()` it at API level 21, then what purpose does it serve?

Comment: You can use `ServerSocketChannel.socket()` to get the underlying `ServerSocket` and call `bind()` on that. `ServerSocketChannel.bind()` was added in Java 1.7. Don't ask me how that relates to API level 24.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thanks for the suggestion! I ended up doing that only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I've found an alternate way to bind the server socket and still use the `ServerSocketChannel` without changing the API level to 24.

```
ServerSocketChannel.open().also {
    it.socket().bind(InetSocketAddress(0))
}
```

I'm still confused about the decision to add `ServerSocketChannel#bind` as late as API level 24.